# Export variable from Bash

Tags: bash

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) I have a function which should **export** some variables, but it doesn't.

Here an *example*:

```sh
function f() {

  # ...
  declare -rx TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
  # ...

}
```

What is the correct way of doing this from within a `function`?

---

#### My environment

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) **v3.2.48(1)-release** [osx](/questions/tagged/osx) **10.8.3**

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to declare the variable as global use the option `-g`. Like this:

```
function f() {

  # ...
  declare -grx TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
  # ...

}
```

quote from `help declare` :

> -d create global variables when used in a shell function; otherwise
>           ignored

---

**Update** After reading your last comment:

> Available outside the function and available in subshells

... it looks like `export` is the command you are looking for. Check this example:

```
function foo {
    export BAR="test"
}

# call function
foo

# will output 'test'
echo "$BAR"

# as the var is in environemt:
export -p | grep "BAR"

# ... it will be available from sub shells as well
```

Note: The `export` solution is missing the `-r` (read-only) feature from declare. If you can live with this, `export` should be ok.

Comment: -bash: declare: -g: invalid option

Comment: Sorry I've not tested with bash 3.2.48. I've tested with 4.2.24 Can you upgrade?

Comment: Wich system still uses 3.2.48 ?  (Will need for testing and further help). What do you mean with *export* ? exporting to environment?

Comment: @Robottinosino What do you mean with export? exporting to environment?

Comment: Bash `4.2` is the earliest version to have `-g` for declare. It's a really new feature.

Comment: Available outside the function and available in subshells?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use declare and your variable will be available outside function as well.

```
function f() {
  # ...
  TIMESTAMP_FORMAT='+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
  # ...
}

f # call your function
echo "OUTSIDE: " $TIMESTAMP_FORMAT
```

Comment: Move the declare outside the function then - if the value is intended to be used globally (I include new processes in that term), it makes sense to declare it in that scope.

Comment: What is the purpose of `-x` then? `man` says: `Mark names for export to subsequent commands via the environment`??

Comment: `subsequent commands via the environment` in the present context i.e. inside that function.

Comment: Alright.. so `declare -x` is absolutely _identical_ to no use of `declare -x` at all, in all cases?